# ST2ST is throwing an error when loading lat/log related to decimal

Tags: syntax-error

It appears that there is an odd non-displayable character in the value coming from VZW. The hex a0 prefixes the latitude value, and this throws off the method to convert a string to a decimal in the StGeolocationConverter class.

This is the most stack trace for error, and a VZW record id that can be investigated.
10:47:25.872 (12891843489)|USER_DEBUG|[1323]|ERROR|Remote Key: a0C0H00001RnioyUAB
(strk.StSiteTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert

```
caused by: strk.StException: Error in packaged trigger handler[strk.StSiteExtendibleTriggerHandler]:SObjectType[strk__Site__c]:Event[before_insert]Message[Invalid decimal:  39.98636000]:
Class.strk.StGeolocationConverter.setLatLong: line 97, column 1
Class.strk.StSiteExtendibleTriggerHandler.beforeInsert: line 36, column 1
Class.strk.StTriggerFactory.execute: line 396, column 1
Class.strk.StTriggerFactory.createAndExecuteHandler: line 253, column 1
Class.strk.StTriggerFactory.createAndExecutePackagedHandler: line 221, column 1
Class.strk.StTriggerFactory.executeTrigger: line 168, column 1
Trigger.strk.StSiteTrigger: line 17, column 1

Class.strk.StTriggerFactory.executeTrigger: line 174, column 1
Trigger.strk.StSiteTrigger: line 17, column 1 / CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY)[enter link description here][1]
```

Link to the zip file containing the logs: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ddxspysuZq_8LNylUMlfshFBTy_YlYGy